# How to run a program in Windows console, starting it by a shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to start a java program in a Windows console from a click to a shortcut in the Quicklaunch area.

How do I do this?

I can start the console (shortcut target: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe) in the desired directory (C:\somewhere) and then start the Java program by typing "java -jar myjar.jar".

I just want to avoid this typing, but the console should stay open. If I use java directly as target, the program runs invisibly (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

The /K option of cmd.exe works for me:
Shortcut target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K java -jar myjar.jar
```

Comment: I found this on some obscure web page. Is there some good, official documenation for cmd.exe somewhere that I could link?

Comment: [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.